# Python - Find clusters and cluster's most central elements from a correlation matrix

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, networkx

I have a created a correlation matrix (based on multiple financial instruments timeseries) with pandas, that is the following:

[image]

(see data below)

I want to cluster the results by correlated elements. I already managed to do that by using a threshold method:

```
# Create a list of correlated pairs
l=list(matrix[(matrix>0.75)|(matrix<-0.75)].stack().index)
li=[item for item in l if item[0]!=item[1]]

# Create a list of groups with correlated instruments
import networkx as nx
gr = nx.Graph(li)
groups=list(nx.connected_components(gr))
```

This returns a list of correlated instruments:

```
[{'AIGCI', 'BZ', 'CL', 'HO', 'QM'},
 {'AUD', 'M6A'},
 {'CHF', 'E7', 'EUR', 'M6E'},
 {'EMD', 'ES', 'NQ', 'RTY', 'YM'},
 {'GBP', 'M6B'},
 {'GC', 'MGC', 'SI'},
 {'GF', 'LE'},
 {'KE', 'ZW'},
 {'NIY', 'NKD'},
 {'TN', 'UB', 'ZB', 'ZF', 'ZN', 'ZT'},
 {'ZM', 'ZS'}]
```

1) Now I would like to to find which one is the most "central" instrument for each of this groups, i.e. the one that is correlated and best correlated to most others in its group.

2) Delving into the documentation of networkx and scikit learn, I was starting to think there might be some more sophisticated way of creating the cluster without entering a threshold value, which i find too arbitrary like [DBscan](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) 
or [affinity propagation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation), or another algorithm from networkx

The problem 1) is the one I am actually trying to solve, but i think this will entails grasping a better understanding of the different clustering algorithms available for that specific task of correlation of timeseries analysis - hence question 2).

If anyone had a turnkey solution for solving 1), that would be awesome.
Alternatively pointers to what algorithm is best suited to cluster correlation matrix elements and perform analysis on the result (like finding the most central element) would be great.

Data:

```
dict_={'AIGCI': {'AIGCI': 1.0,
  'AUD': 0.3233391012080904,
  'BZ': 0.77450612217810844,
  'CAD': 0.37758495673263409,
  'CHF': 0.1148713675671198,
  'CL': 0.75790671332995785,
  'E7': 0.15824972293693412,
  'EMD': 0.20907406346059357,
  'ES': 0.19658499045886685,
  'EUR': 0.15900870599662253},
 'AUD': {'AIGCI': 0.3233391012080904,
  'AUD': 1.0,
  'BZ': 0.16539566069043321,
  'CAD': 0.56525172934861501,
  'CHF': 0.39333882276815396,
  'CL': 0.16369950005905545,
  'E7': 0.41552240077868813,
  'EMD': 0.20167148908243152,
  'ES': 0.24541480412857969,
  'EUR': 0.41986142158397494},
 'BZ': {'AIGCI': 0.77450612217810844,
  'AUD': 0.16539566069043321,
  'BZ': 1.0,
  'CAD': 0.41187046918391457,
  'CHF': -0.0092838918317396726,
  'CL': 0.97045709275661984,
  'E7': 0.0095197228846883777,
  'EMD': 0.20634087929447745,
  'ES': 0.1923482593409139,
  'EUR': 0.012112114472331318},
 'CAD': {'AIGCI': 0.37758495673263409,
  'AUD': 0.56525172934861501,
  'BZ': 0.41187046918391457,
  'CAD': 1.0,
  'CHF': 0.35191789369432458,
  'CL': 0.40972181454072104,
  'E7': 0.31846852856331664,
  'EMD': 0.28026489729302623,
  'ES': 0.29256826563873206,
  'EUR': 0.32757564057495203},
 'CHF': {'AIGCI': 0.1148713675671198,
  'AUD': 0.39333882276815396,
  'BZ': -0.0092838918317396726,
  'CAD': 0.35191789369432458,
  'CHF': 1.0,
  'CL': 0.012688599148050395,
  'E7': 0.8239125068633365,
  'EMD': -0.13725408324352331,
  'ES': -0.1041381030850365,
  'EUR': 0.82474780532058567},
 'CL': {'AIGCI': 0.75790671332995785,
  'AUD': 0.16369950005905545,
  'BZ': 0.97045709275661984,
  'CAD': 0.40972181454072104,
  'CHF': 0.012688599148050395,
  'CL': 1.0,
  'E7': 0.0073086434159336097,
  'EMD': 0.22554220312864581,
  'ES': 0.20407792352963819,
  'EUR': 0.011629405332006879},
 'E7': {'AIGCI': 0.15824972293693412,
  'AUD': 0.41552240077868813,
  'BZ': 0.0095197228846883777,
  'CAD': 0.31846852856331664,
  'CHF': 0.8239125068633365,
  'CL': 0.0073086434159336097,
  'E7': 1.0,
  'EMD': -0.14561549010272393,
  'ES': -0.10852020039517689,
  'EUR': 0.99165451800731141},
 'EMD': {'AIGCI': 0.20907406346059357,
  'AUD': 0.20167148908243152,
  'BZ': 0.20634087929447745,
  'CAD': 0.28026489729302623,
  'CHF': -0.13725408324352331,
  'CL': 0.22554220312864581,
  'E7': -0.14561549010272393,
  'EMD': 1.0,
  'ES': 0.85791959540783203,
  'EUR': -0.13599101777284797},
 'ES': {'AIGCI': 0.19658499045886685,
  'AUD': 0.24541480412857969,
  'BZ': 0.1923482593409139,
  'CAD': 0.29256826563873206,
  'CHF': -0.1041381030850365,
  'CL': 0.20407792352963819,
  'E7': -0.10852020039517689,
  'EMD': 0.85791959540783203,
  'ES': 1.0,
  'EUR': -0.10635681098349807},
 'EUR': {'AIGCI': 0.15900870599662253,
  'AUD': 0.41986142158397494,
  'BZ': 0.012112114472331318,
  'CAD': 0.32757564057495203,
  'CHF': 0.82474780532058567,
  'CL': 0.011629405332006879,
  'E7': 0.99165451800731141,
  'EMD': -0.13599101777284797,
  'ES': -0.10635681098349807,
  'EUR': 1.0}}

import pandas as pd
matrix=pd.DataFrame(dict_)
```

Answer (score 0):

On filtering: an alternative way to filter is to use [Serrano's disparity filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disparity_filter_algorithm_of_weighted_network). You can find a networkx-compatible solution [here](https://github.com/aekpalakorn/python-backbone-network). Basically for each node it tests all adjacent edge weights against a null hypothesis of a uniform distribution. You can set a threshold and keep only those edges which are significant at that value.

On detecting clusters: there are many methods to detect communities in a weighted network without filtering until you have multiple connected components. One out of the box method that works fairly well (and handles weights) with an networkx-compatible implementation is the [Louvain algorithm](https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain).

On detecting important nodes in the cluster: if you've filtered and found clusters, you could simple rank the nodes within cluster by their weighted degree or closeness centrality. Networkx has a [convenient function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html) for taking subgraphs given a list of nodes.